# What does "put it down on me" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, lyrics

What does the phrase ["put it down on me"](http://metrolyrics.com/down-on-me-lyrics-jeremih.html) mean?

Comment: More context please? Where did you see this? If it's online, could you provide a link?

Comment: @Martha: i was refering to Jeremih's song: Down On Me
http://www.metrolyrics.com/down-on-me-lyrics-jeremih.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That song appears to have a dual meaning of the phrase.

> we’ll buy another round and it’s all on me
>   
> as long as I’m around put it down on me

Implies "I'll pay for it". Put it down (Put the bill) on me (on my tab) so to speak.

"Have a round on the house" means the bar is giving a free drink. If someone says "Have a drink, it's on me" is someone offering a free drink.

However the song also implies a more sexual meaning as well.

> girl all I really want is you down on me
>   
> put it down on me

Read more: http://www.killerhiphop.com/jeremih-down-on-me-lyrics-50-cent/#ixzz1G7TLDcVg

Comment: Worth noting that the sexual meaning appears in other pop songs as well (e.g. Maroon 5 - "Sugar" has "Your sugar / Yes, please / Won't you come and put it down on me?"). Based on this it doesn't appear to refer exclusively to oral sex but rather sex in general.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really mean much of anything by itself, but in the context of the song, it is a vague double entendre for oral sex.

Answer (score 0):

I think a careful reading of these particular lyrics will show that this song is about sodomy, with the "it" in the phrase referring to Shawty's rear end.

Answer (score 0):

The song means for the girl to put it down on the man or to have sex.

Comment: Dear Brooke, please use the [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/23756/edit) link under your original answer rather than re-posting it.